# How to detect input field change in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have group of input fields( I am not using form),I need to detect if any one of them is changed by user, before user leave the page, I need to show a popup, How can I make it happen? I need a function like checkchanges, if changes, will return false/true. something like this.
I try to use$scope.$watch and angular.forEach to loop all input ng-model, but seems like doesn't work out.

Comment: `ng-model` should apply `ng-dirty` css class to changed fields. So you can just simply look for existence of elements with this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form), any inputs that where changed are given the `ng-dirty` class by AngularJS.

Look for any input fields with this class.

Comment: if we are editing an input field and clearing it using the backspace button the "ng-dirty" will be true. so we cant use it for showing pop up here